# Error reindexing fulltext search after elasticsearch had been enabled on Nexcess cloud hosting (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, error, elasticsearch, indexer, reindexing

I get this error when trying to run the indexer for the search:

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`

```
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Types 
cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name 
parameter is set to 
true."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Types cannot be 
provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter 
is set to true."},"status":400}
```

Any advice? I can't proceed to update Magento 2 as Elasticsearch is required now.

This is a new installation that has not seen much modification apart from installing litextension for data migration.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Following checks will somehow narrow down the problem site is having.

1. check which **Magento specific version** you are using
2. which **ElasticSearch** version is installed on server
3. which **ElasticSearch** version is configured under **Catalog Search engine** in system configuration?

If site is migrated recently then check [Magento dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/) which ElasticSearch version suitable to which Magento version.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you mentioned us and would love to help you with your problem!

For Magento 2.4 and above, you need to use elasticsearch 7.x version, and in this version, type_name is no longer available.

Please navigate accordingly: config => catalog => catalog to check which version you are using, if you are using 5x or 6x, please change your config to the 7x version. And then use param include_type_name = true instead.

Hope that help!